# Pixelated Monaco font in Ubuntu 18

Tags: fonts

I just installed monaco font into ubuntu, but when I open IntelliJ Idea and use this font it is pixelated. I also use it in terminal where looks good, but in Idea terrible:

[image]

Can you tell me how to fix it please?

I tried add this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match target="font">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
           <string>Monaco</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="embeddedbitmap">
            <bool>false</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

in file ~/config/fontconfig/conf.d/20-no-embedded.conf but doesn't help.

Comment: How did you install that font? I tried to install [this one](https://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Monaco/) with gnome-font-viewer and I don't have any problem with pixelation in PyCharm.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it in monday and give you response. I found some font on internet and install it by double click on it.

Comment: @BlueManCZ yes, your version of monaco works fine. thank you.

Comment: Good to hear that, you are welcome.